# What does this say in Elvish?

Tags: tolkien-languages

I was recently in a building, and someone wrote this on a table:

[image: Image of a word in a Tolkien-made language]

It seems to be Elvish. What does it translate to?

Comment: "Clean me"....?

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's not Elvish, it's the Tengwar script.

Comment: @curiousdannii makes an important point. If I wrote the characters sigma tau omega pi, I wouldn't have written the Greek for "stop".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I admit to little skill, but it appears to say approximately "stargazing."

[s][t+a][r][ng+a][z+i][n][ng]  (Note that there is no simple "g" sound in Quenya.)

I ruled out Sindarin in favor of Quenya because Sindarin diphthongs place the vowel *before* the consonant, which would give "satragizng."

Thanks to Mark in the comments for pointing out the clarification:  this is an *English* word written using the Tengwar *script* in the Quenya *mode*.

Comment: So English then I guess.

Comment: @ibid Remember that the runes and Tengwar in the title pages were all transliterated English.

Comment: Specifically, it looks like it's English written in the Tengwar script using the Quenya mode (as opposed to actual Quenya written in the Tengwar script).

Comment: Elennapalantirië  (?)